# python mechanize javascript submit button problem!

Tags: python, mechanize, urlopen

im making some script with mechanize.browser module.

one of problem is all other thing is ok, but when submit() form,it not working,

so i was found some suspicion source part.

in the html source i was found such like following.

im thinking, loginCheck(this) making problem when submit form.

but how to handle this kind of javascript function with mechanize module ,so i can

successfully submit form and can receive result?

following is websource snippet which related with loginCheck(this) javascript function.

```
        function init(){
        FRMLOGIN.ID.focus();
    }

    function loginCheck(f){
        if(chkNull(f.ID, "아이디를"))
            return false;

        if(chkNull(f.PWD, "패스워드를"))
            return false;

        //f.target = "ifrmLoginHidden";
        f.action = (f.SECCHK.checked) ? "https://user.buddybuddy.co.kr/Login/Login.asp" : "http://user.buddybuddy.co.kr/Login/Login.asp";
    }
```

i know mechanize not support javascript, so i want to make progammatically  loginCheck()

function with python mechanize code.

anyone would you some help me to make this javascript function to python mechanize

translated code?

so correctly can login with website?

if so much appreciate!

```
    # -*- coding: cp949-*-
import sys,os
import mechanize, urllib
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup,BeautifulStoneSoup,Tag
import datetime, time, socket
import re,sys,os,mechanize,urllib,time


br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# Want debugging messages?
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
br.set_debug_responses(True)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6')]
br.open('http://user.buddybuddy.co.kr/Login/LoginForm.asp?URL=')
html = br.response().read()
print html

br.select_form(name='FRMLOGIN')
print br.viewing_html()
br.form['ID']='psh7943'
br.form['PWD']='qkrthgus'
br.submit()

print br.response().read()
```

if anyone can help me ..much appreciate!!

Comment: Please tell me those are just dummy user/pass strings.

Answer (score 4):

You can go through the login process by hand in your browser and check (using e.g. Firebug in firefox, Developer Tools in Chrome etc.) what requests are sent to the site when you hit the OK button. Usually this is a POST request with data taken from the login form. Check what data are sent in this request and execute your own post request with:

```
mechanize.urlopen(URL, POST_DATA).
```

You can extract POST_DATA (and post_url) from mechanize's form object using:

```
form.click_request_data()
```

but you may need to do some modifications.

Very simple example:

```
br.select_form(name='form_name')
br.form['login']='login'
br.form['pass']='pass'
post_url, post_data, headers =  br.form.click_request_data()
mechanize.urlopen(post_url, post_data)
```

Comment: What if doing so produces `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 414: Request-URI Too Large`, but the requests works fine in a normal browser?